How to use an AU plugin in my iOS project?
I got a plugin and it resides at /Library/Audio/Plug-Ins. Inside, there is a Components folder, inside of which there is a .components file. I simply added it to my project.
The thing is, the Audio Unit instantiation always fails with error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-3000 "(null)".
I've never worked with Audio Units before, so I'm clueless!
Here's my code:
class TestViewController: UIViewController {
var audioEngine = AVAudioEngine()
var audioUnit: AVAudioUnit?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    loadAudioUnit()
}

func loadAudioUnit() {
    let componentDescription = AudioComponentDescription(componentType: kAudioUnitType_Effect,
                                                         componentSubType: FourCharCode("Tuna"), // Replace with actual subtype
                                                         componentManufacturer: FourCharCode("StSt"), // Replace with actual manufacturer
                                                         componentFlags: 0,
                                                         componentFlagsMask: 0)
    
    AVAudioUnit.instantiate(with: componentDescription, options: []) { (audioUnit, error) in
        guard let audioUnit = audioUnit else {
            print("Error instantiating audio unit: \(String(describing: error))")
            return
        }
        self.audioUnit = audioUnit
        self.audioEngine.attach(audioUnit)
        self.connectAudioNodes()
    }
}

func connectAudioNodes() {
    guard let audioUnit = audioUnit else { return }
    let inputNode = audioEngine.inputNode
    let outputNode = audioEngine.outputNode
    let format = inputNode.inputFormat(forBus: 0)
    
    audioEngine.connect(inputNode, to: audioUnit, format: format)
    audioEngine.connect(audioUnit, to: outputNode, format: format)
    
    do {
        try audioEngine.start()
    } catch {
        print("Failed to start audio engine: \(error)")
    }
}

func setParameter(parameterID: AUParameterAddress, value: Float) {
    guard let audioUnit = audioUnit else { return }
    guard let parameterTree = audioUnit.auAudioUnit.parameterTree else { return }
    
    if let parameter = parameterTree.parameter(withAddress: parameterID) {
        parameter.value = value
    } else {
        print("Parameter with ID \(parameterID) not found.")
    }
}

func FourCharCode(_ string: String) -> UInt32 {
    var result: UInt32 = 0
    if let data = string.data(using: .macOSRoman) {
        data.withUnsafeBytes { (rawBytes: UnsafeRawBufferPointer) in
            if let bytes = rawBytes.baseAddress?.assumingMemoryBound(to: UInt8.self) {
                result = UInt32(bytes[3]) | (UInt32(bytes[2]) << 8) | (UInt32(bytes[1]) << 16) | (UInt32(bytes[0]) << 24)
            }
        }
    }
    return result
}}

Am I doing anything wrong?
